# How to add language dropdown in admin form like cms page

Tags: magento2, adminform, magento-2.0.7

I am new to magento 2, I created an admin module. In this module the text what we entered in admin content. It reflects on the frontend. But the problem is if we change the language to other than english. The text is still displaying to english only. In CMS Pages it has a dropdown to select the language. I want to have over. here.

Answer (score 0):

You must defind language file csv at i18n directory. Examble: you want use japan language, you must have file ja_JP.csv at i18n directory. 
i18n directory => can each module or theme ... 
More information:

```
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am already having my language csv but still cant able to translate it. While creating cms pages will getting one dropdown like store view. How to approach that in my custom module is my question.